# react native track player remote next function

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-track-player

I have a problem changing track to the next with react-native-track-player.

I need to change the track while music playing in background and I am on iOS locked screen with controls.

According to react-native-track-player documentation (http://react-native-track-player.js.org/documentation/) I made an implementation.

I have a service.js file:

```
import TrackPlayer, {Event} from 'react-native-track-player';
import {tracks} from './src/components/audioPlayer/tracks';

module.exports = async function () {
  TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-play' as Event, () =>
    TrackPlayer.play(),
  );

  TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-pause' as Event, () =>
    TrackPlayer.pause(),
  );

  TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-stop' as Event, () =>
    TrackPlayer.destroy(),
  );

  TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemotePrevious, async (e: any) => {
    const currentTrackIndex = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
    if (currentTrackIndex > 0) {
      try {
        await TrackPlayer.skipToPrevious();
        console.log('remote previous succeeded');
      } catch {
        console.log('remote previous error');
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  });

  TrackPlayer.addEventListener(Event.RemoteNext, async (e: any) => {
    const currentTrackIndex = await TrackPlayer.getCurrentTrack();
    if (currentTrackIndex < tracks.length - 1) {
      try {
        await TrackPlayer.skipToNext();
        console.log('remote next succeeded');
      } catch {
        console.log('remote next error');
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
  });

  TrackPlayer.addEventListener('remote-seek' as Event, async (position) =>
    TrackPlayer.seekTo(position.position),
  );
```

I made the capability configuration in my component file.

The track player works fine in the app, I can pause, play, skipToNext, skipToPrevious.

My problem is:
The player works also fine when I am on the locked screen with background playing and I do play, pause, but when I do a skipToNext or skipToPrevious here, it goes to paused state (and I can not start from locked screen - but if I open the device I see that the track was changed).

Here are my logs from xCode:

```
2021-10-06 12:10:24.148543+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] 'New event: ', { state: 'playing', type: 'playback-state' }
2021-10-06 12:10:24.148677+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] state play
2021-10-06 12:10:27.719001+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] 'New event: ', { type: 'remote-next' }
2021-10-06 12:10:27.719153+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] Event remote next state
Skipping to next track
2021-10-06 12:10:27.930207+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] remote next succeeded
2021-10-06 12:10:27.950990+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] 'New event: ', { track: 1,
  nextTrack: 2,
  position: 3.49197814,
  type: 'playback-track-changed' }
2021-10-06 12:10:27.951244+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] Event track changed
2021-10-06 12:10:28.019813+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] CURRENT TRACK useeffect:
2021-10-06 12:10:28.030528+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] { id: 2,
  url: 'https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-3.mp3',
  title: 'Kalkbass',
  artist: 'Bar Horse',
  album: '',
  duration: 344 }
2021-10-06 12:10:28.428465+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] 'New event: ', { state: 'paused', type: 'playback-state' }
2021-10-06 12:10:28.428566+0200 [52842:2962646] [javascript] state paused
Starting/Resuming playback
```

So the question:
What would be the problem?
Do you have proper implementation for changing track in background from locked screen iOS?
Any help would be appreciated.

Versions:
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.65.1",
"react-native-track-player": "^2.1.1",
xCode: 13.0
iOS (real device tested): 15.0

Comment: Does somewone has the same issue. I have it also and i dont know what te problem is. I have the problem on Android BTW